# What's the source of this HQL query error?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

```
    public List<UserDto> getTopUsersForDaysRankedByNumberOfQuestions(Integer daysCount, Integer usersCount) {
        return entityManager.createQuery(
                "select new com.javamentor.qa.platform.models.dto.UserDto(" +
                        "user.id, " +
                        "user.email, " +
                        "user.fullName, " +
                        "user.imageLink, " +
                        "user.city, " +
                        "(select sum(case when rep.count is null then 0 else rep.count end) " +
                        "from Reputation as rep where rep.author.id = user.id)), " +
                        "sum(case when vote.vote = 'UP_VOTE' then 1 when vote.vote = 'DOWN_VOTE' then - 1 else 0 end) as sumVotes, " +
                        "count(distinct answer.id) as answerCount " +
                        "from User as user " +
                        "inner join Answer as answer on answer.id = user.id " +
                        "left join VoteAnswer as vote on answer.id = vote.id " +
                        "where answer.persistDateTime > :date " +
                        "and answer.isDeleted = false " +
                        "and user.isDeleted = false " +
                        "group by user.id " +
                        "order by answerCount desc,sumVotes desc,user.id", UserDto.class)
                .setParameter("date", LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(daysCount))
                .setMaxResults(usersCount)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

So I have this method which should return List of UserDto but I'm getting the erorrs. Tried to fix this whole day but I still don't understand the source of these errors

```
o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:299: unexpected token: ,
o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:299: unexpected token: ,
o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:392: expecting EOF, found ')'
o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:392: expecting EOF, found ')'
```

Is this somehow syntax related or I'm doing something completely wrong?

Comment: `rep.author.id = user.id))` looks like a closing parenthesis too many

Comment: Yea, maybe. I thought I need first parenthesis for closing internal sql query and second for UserDto constructor

Comment: Show your input strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a simple select dto from user, and if that works add the rest of the query sentence by sentence until you find the one that throws the error.